# Estou com uma duvida em uma aplicação web usando node.js e como aplicar o if dentro do js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, if, else

```
//não sei como colocar o if dentro dessa apicação. Preciso que o resultado se for acima de 1250 entre com um desconto de 4,5%.


var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

var servidor = app.listen(8080, function() {
    var porta = servidor.address().port;
    console.log("Servidor executando na porta %s", porta);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./form-input.html',
        function(erro, resultado) {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write(resultado);
            res.end();
        });

});

app.post('/Total', urlencodedParser,
    function(req, res) {
        fs.readFile('./form-output.html',
            function(erro, resultado) {
            var resultado = resultado.toString().replace("{{Total}}", (parseInt(req.body.quantidade) * parseInt(req.body.preçouni)));
            var desconto = resultado * 0.045;
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            if (resultado > 1250) {
                res.write(resultado);
                res.end();
            }
                });
            })
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, além da formatação, vejo que há um problema na lógica da execução aí:

Tu estás retornando para o cliente apenas se o resultado for maior que 1250, e está retornando o valor sem o desconto aplicado, então o funcionamento fica totalmente errado.

Minha sugestão de abordagem pra resolver isso é:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
var servidor = app.listen(8080, function() { var porta = servidor.address().port; console.log("Servidor executando na porta %s", porta); });

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./form-input.html', function(erro, resultado) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write(resultado);
        res.end();
    });
});

app.post('/Total', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./form-output.html', function(erro, resultado) {
        var resultado = resultado.toString().replace("{{Total}}", (parseInt(req.body.quantidade) * parseInt(req.body.preçouni)));
        
        if (resultado > 1250) {
            var desconto = 4.5;
            var descontoAPlicado = (100 - desconto) / 100;

            resultado = resultado * descontoAPlicado;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write(resultado);
        res.end();
    });
})
```

Ajustei o cálculo do desconto também, na abordagem anterior tu estava cobrando 4.5% do valor final, ao invés de aplicar um desconto.